# multiple select list c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a multiple select from a single select drop down menu.
my model originally had:

```
public int country_id { get; set; }
```

and my view had:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("country_id", String.Empty)
```

to change it to multiple select i changed my model to:

```
public List<Country> country_id { get; set; }
```

and my view to:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.country_id, ViewBag.ActionsList as MultiSelectList, new { @class = "multiselect", @style = "width: 450px;height:200px" })
```

the problem i am having is updating my databse using migration since the i am changing `int` to `list`, however, it keeps saying

> "Cannot drop the index 'dbo.People.IX_country_id', because it does
>   not exist or you do not have permission."

I do have permission so I am not sure if I am missing something?

My list of countries is coming straight from the country database.

thanks for your inputs.

Comment: What is the question about ? The problem with the index or the view?

Comment: the problem is when i do the database migration to update from int to a list, it is not updating it. so the model doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to populate a selectlist in the controller & pass it to the view, something like this:

```
var countries = from d in db.Countries
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = d.Id,
                            Name = d.Name
                        };
// I'd pass this in a model, but use ViewBag if that's what you're familiar with
ViewBag.ActionsList =  new SelectList(countries , "Id", "Name");
```

And in the View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.country_id, ViewBag.ActionsList)
```

**UPDATE:**

You should use a ViewModel for this:

```
public class CountryList
{
    // this may have to be a List<SelectListItems> to work with MultiSelectList - check.
    public SelectList Countries{ get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedCountryIds { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller:

```
var model = new CountryList
{
    SelectList = //assign the selectlist created earlier
}
return View(model);
```

In the View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCountryIds, new MultiSelectList(@Model.Countries, "Id", "Name", @Model.SelectedCountryIds))
```

Comment: the problem is when i do the database migration to update from int to a list, it is not updating it. so the model doesn't get updated.

Comment: Don't update it to a list, that won't work. It needs to stay as an `int`.

Comment: i have another question, so if i am not updating to a list, how do i store/save the selected lists from the drop down?

Comment: I see why you were trying update the Id to List - I've update the answer

Comment: this is wonderful. so i need my regular database model, and a view model:-) bingo, thanks.

Comment: In the original code it would need to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.country_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.ActionsList)`, and in the Edit, the controller would need to be `Countries = // assign the selectlist` and the view should be `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCountryIds, Model.Countries)`